# Coredata fetch using inherited property

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a data model as follows.

```
Chat -> abstract entity
ChatUser -> inhertied from Chat. 
         -> has a relationship to user model that has a name attribute
ChatGroup -> inherited from Chat
          -> has a relationship to group that also has a name attribute.
```

I need to fetch all chats using a fetchedresultscontroller that have the name "ABC" from either the user name or the group name. I can't seem to fetch them using a single predicate. Is there a way I can fetch both of them individually and combine the results.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract entities cannot be instantiated, so you won't be able to get them back in a fetch request. Keep `Chat` as parent entity of the other two, but don't make it abstract.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMOM.html

Comment: Thats not true. If I create a fetch request for the super abstract entity (Chat), it will actually return me all the sub-entities.